# Android - Open Accessibility Settings of specific Application

Tags: java, android

I have code in method **openAccessiblitySettings()** where I **startActivity** and "**redirect**" user **to Accessibility Settings**.

```java
public void openAccessiblitySettings()
{
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);

    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Is there any option to redirect to a specific page in the settings of a specific application ?**

Using maybe something like:

```java
Uri.parse("package:" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)
```

Similar to this:

```java
public void openApplicationDetailsSettings()
{
    final Intent intent = new Intent(
        Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
        Uri.parse("package:" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)
    );

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);

    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```